# Ошибка при работе с двумерными динамическими массивами "Вызвано исключение по адресу: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу ". C++

Tags: c++, массивы, права-доступа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;int main()
{
    int i;
    int n;
    int k, g = 0;
    cin >> i >> n;
    int**a = new int*[i];
    for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
    {
        a[i] = new int[n];
    }
    int* line = new int[i * n];

    for (int p = 0; p < i; p++)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)
        {
            a[p][q] = rand() % 100;
            line[g] = a[p][q];
            g++;
        }
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < i * n; p++)
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < (i * n) - 1; u++) 
        {                                   
            if (line[u] > line[u + 1])    
            {                           
                k = line[u];//              
                line[u] = line[u + 1]; 
                line[u + 1] = k;            
            }                           
        }                               
    }                                       
    g = 0;                              
    for (int p = 0; p < i; p++)         
    {                                       
        for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)     
        {                                   
            a[p][q] = line[g];      
            g++;
            cout << a[p][q] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум

```
for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
{
    a[i] = new int[n];
}
```

Видите?  `i` раз присваиваете значение одному и тому же элементу за пределами массива.

Совет: именуйте переменные согласованно.

Второй совет: хоть немного смотрите своим исходники перед тем, как выставлять такие проблемы на всеобщее обозрение...